# Chrome - Copy/Paste URL from Address Bar retains font formatting

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, url, clipboard, copy-paste

When you copy and paste a URL from the address bar of FireFox or IE it is put on the clipboard as plain text.

When you copy and paste a URL from the address bar of Chrome it is put on the clipboard as formatted text in Times New Roman font.

Having to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> every time I paste a URL into an email or Word doc is getting very boring!

I do have PureText set up to paste plain text on <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> but most of the time I forget to use it with Chrome URLs and end up doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>.

Is there any way to force Chrome to use plain text like FF and IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug in Chrome / Chromium which has been around since version 0.2

Bug report filed on Sep 3, 2008: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=976

Reading through the comments it's not very high on the list of priorities to fix.